# Where can I find a (partial) list of 'big charities' based in the UK which already use CiviCRM?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I'm volunteering for a small UK-based charity interested in switching its CRM system (from Insightly to something which addresses more of their requirements). It would be reassuring for them to see a (partial) list of 'big charities' based in the UK which already use CiviCRM. I think I've recently come across such a list but I can't now for the life of me recall where I may have seen it. Does such a list exist online? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A google search like

> "civicrm/contribute/transact" site:.uk

will give a lot of results for UK users of civi (of course only those which use a contribution form)

You may also find some useful names at https://civicrm.org/case-studies

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful. I looked through the case studies and picked out these ones which are UK related: Greater London Volunteering, Tameside, Oldham and Glossop Mind, George House Trust, British Humanist Society, City of London Club, The Challenging Behaviour Foundation, and British Geriatrics Society. The search on UK users of CiviCRM is also super helpful, as the charity I'm helping out is particularly interested in processing payments themselves. Thanks again.

Comment: "processing payments themselves"?

Comment: as in, have a payment processor, eg Stripe, PayPal, etc, etc that is wired directly to their CRM? You have probably seen this list: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/#comparison

Comment: Also others such as GoCardless for non-credit card type transactions.

Comment: Right. By "processing payments themselves" I mean using a service like Strip, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That is complicated in the open source world :-) The community only knows about organizations using CiviCRM when they tell us about it. There is no contract that needs signing or anything like that. Anything that does exist online will very likely be incomplete and potentially incorrect.

I can tell you about 2 of my customers in the UK that use CiviCRM: Article19 (https://www.article19.org/) and NIHR BioResource (https://bioresource.nihr.ac.uk/). But please note that they might use other parts of CiviCRM than your organization might be aiming for?

There is also this more general information: https://civicrm.org/blog/cividesk/how-many-organizations-use-civicrm-where-how

Comment: Thank you. They are two nice examples.